# Can we make chromatography less troublesome?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

Thin Layer Chromatography is a very powerful method in analytical chemistry for separating complicated chemical matrices.

As an engineer, I am interested to build device capable of automating TLC such that I can just place a droplet of my sample onto a piece of paper and let the device perform the TLC for me.

How achievable is this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_performance_thin_layer_chromatography

Comment: ^^ So, to answer your question: It is very achievable. Just don't try to patent it unless you come up with some innovative new addition.

Comment: Are there HPLC machines out there that will automatically lower my plate into a solvent front? Would it be possible to automate this process such that a person with no chemistry background would be able to use?

Comment: And also, something less than 50 USD?

Comment: We can't even get a box of TLC plates for less than 50 USD.

Comment: @SendersReagent I have UTLC plates with Silica (http://www.google.ch/patents/US8810789) costing about 1 dollar per cm squared.

Comment: Although it may be useful for science facilities with low resources, I am not sure if it will provide anything that is in a way better than more functional chromatography methods: gas chromatography, liquid chromatography, ion chromatography, etc. With these and a combination of detectors (FID, ECD, Mass Spectrometers) we can pretty much separate and detect any mixture of compounds. Furthermore, chemometrics  improves identification by using data generated by these procedures.

Comment: If you equate "less troublesome" with more automation of sample deposit and development: http://www.camag.com/en/tlc_hptlc/products/sample_application/automatic_tlc_sampler_4_ats_4.cfm (as an example).